# How can I achieve layout like below using layout xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

**[image: Layout that I want to Achieve]**

In below layout there are two TouchImageViews. What I want to achieve is that, for any device these two TouchImageViews remains in center as well as their height should be 1.5 of device height. And each TouchImageView width should be half of device`s width. And as show in image there should be space on top and bottom for other stuffs.

**Edit:**
Sorry, My mistake I need 0.75 height of TouchImageView of device height.

Comment: Are you sure you mean that their height should be 1.5 of device height? That would make it bigger than the device, meaning there wouldn't be any space for stuff on top and bottom

Comment: 1.5 of device height? I will be longer than the device.

Comment: If you are using linearlayout, use layout_weight attribute. Eg., layout_weight = "0.5" for width of imageviews.

Comment: Add comment if downvoting, helps newbies..

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I need 0.75 height of device height@Everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_one"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_two"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:weightSum="2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/im_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@android:color/white" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/in_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_three"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, dude. Your answer did not provide me exact solution but my problem is solved through your answer. Thanks a lot.@ask4solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Relative Layout for the same.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/flSpaceOne">Space for other stuff</FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_below="android:id="@+id/flSpaceOne" android:layout_above="android:id="@+id/flSpaceTwo">
        <ImageView android:layout_weight="1" ></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:layout_weight="1" ></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/flSpaceTwo" android:align_parent_bottom="true">Space for other stuff</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

To set the height of the Image layout, you need to set it programatically by setting the height of linear layout.

Comment: Need to set through xml layout file only@Eldhose M Babu